# Help in understanding a Capacitive Voltage Transformer

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, voltage-measurement, resonance

I have been reading up about CVT’s and trying to comprehend some of the parts of the typical circuit which include:
A potential divider (C1 & C2).
An inductor tapped from the potential divider.
A small step down transformer.
A burden.

When this is for a 396 kV system: the capacitance values reduce the voltage across C2 to around 12 kV and the divider has approximately 350 mA flowing through it.

I understand first of all that as current is drawn from the divider (burden increases) that the potential dividers output ratio ceases to represent the primary voltage accurately as the impedance of the divider changes.

First question is: why do we say the burden on the potential divider increases, when it is the lowering of the impedance which causes the current to flow through the high impedance input? Note:I understand this for CTs (an increase in burden is an increase in resistance which will eventually saturate the CT).

When an inductor is tapped from the potential divider I understand that this creates a resonant circuit and allows current to pass through the divider.

Question 2, why does this not reduce the accuracy of the potential divider in the way described above, if the current in the circuit changes, won’t the voltage divider?

Question 3, why is the resonance (inductor value) tuned to the total capacitance when it is not in series with C1 and C2 and not tuned to the capacitance seen at the potential dividers output C2?

Comment: Can anyone at least recommend where to look?